# Modeling language for Block-Chain-Oriented Systems

Tags: contract-design, design-patterns

Any ideas about how do i use graphic models for representations. Should i follow UML diagrams style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UML is ok and it does the job. And for contracts there is a nice tool to help representation. https://github.com/raineorshine/solgraph